# Add DOM Element that spans several nodes

Tags: javascript, html, dom

let's assume the following basic HTML:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <p> This is the content of paragraph 1. </p>
            <p> This is the content of paragraph 2. </p>
            <p> This is the content of paragraph 3. </p>
            <p> This is the content of paragraph 4. </p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Let's also assume, that I have a list of all text nodes `nodes`. So e.g. `nodes[0]` would return the text node corresponding to the first paragraph and `nodes[0].parentNOde` would return the actual `<p>` element of the first paragraph.

I want to be able to highlight any substring. Let's say I want to Highlight the text
`content of paragraph 1.  This is the content of paragraph 2.`

What I have is the indices of the nodes as well as the offset for the text to be highlighted. So in this example, I'd have given the following:

`start_node_index = 0`

`stat_node_offset = 14`

`end_nod_index = 1`

`end_node_offset = 0`

Note: The offsets are in respect to the characters of the text string of the given node. For start we count from the left, for end we count from the right.

So to summarizes: Given is the HTML resp. DOM, the actual string to be highlighted as well as the location in the DOM tree based on self-made indexing.

How can I now highlight the string? I don't care if we use `spans` with CSS or `<mark>` elements.

Can we somehow simply add `<mark>` at the start and `</mark>` at the end and let the DOM update algorithm handle the DOM update for us or do I have to write a sophisticated algorithm that handles all the edge cases myself?

The optimal solution here, would be to add `<mark>` once for the text in the first paragraph and then again for the second paragraph. Is it possible to somehow automate this, so I don't have to care about it?

I want to add: Since we have a list of nodes for all text nodes, we also know all text nodes between the start and end node from which we can construct the whole sub-tree, which in turn would make it possible to write my own algorithm but I really would like to not do that.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to highlight any substring. Let's say I want to
> Highlight the text `content of paragraph 1.  This is the content of paragraph 2.`

Some browsers (except Firefox and Safari for now) support [**Text Fragments**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Text_fragments#examples), which is pretty much what you want, but instead of calculating the offsets manually, you specify two keywords that delimit the start (`textStart`) and end (`textEnd`) of the text you want to highlight, and the browser does the job automatically. You can also specify the whole string that you want to highlight. So in your case, it would be as simple as:

[https://yoursite.com/#:~:text=content of paragraph 1.  This is the content of paragraph 2.](https://yoursite.com/#:%7E:text=content%20of%20paragraph%201.%20%20This%20is%20the%20content%20of%20paragraph%202.)

If you don't want to pass that link to your users you can have a script that adds the fragment automatically. Something like:

```
function highlightText(text){
    location.hash = ":~:text=" + encodeURIComponent(text);
    history.replaceState(null, null, " "); // this removes the hash from URL
}
```

Then you can highlight one or multiple texts by calling the function `highlightText`:

```
highlightText("content of paragraph 1. This is the content of paragraph 2.");
highlightText("another text");
```

Notice that changing the `location.hash` property does not cause a redirection, that is, the page is not reloaded.

It is also possible to change the default style of the selected text (via `::target-text`). See [Styling matched text fragments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Text_fragments#styling_matched_text_fragments).